# Can transistors be made in the stone age? (Spoiler: Dr.Stone)

Tags: science-based, technology, hard-science, technological-development, stoneage

**WARNING: This post contains some spoilers for the anime/manga *Dr.Stone*.**

As I'm watching Dr.Stone, I see Senku and the gang trying to make vacuum tubes for their circuits. The vacuum tube is an ancestor to the transistor. It is quite hard to make and is fragile because glass is used to enclose a vacuum and the metal (Tungsten) inside has to get quite hot. Transistors, however, can be tiny and easy to use. I know enough Physics and Electrical Engineering to know pretty well how transistors work but I'm not sure how they can be made.

The environment and circumstances in the world of *Dr. Stone*:

- There's a single (genius) scientist from the modern world (everyone in the world got turned into stone and some got unpetrified after some thousands of years)
- They can do metal work and smithing
- They have a water wheel that can generate some electricity
- They also have some batteries
- They're making wires out of gold
- A furnace is available but runs on either manual pumping or on the water wheel
- Many common metals are available

Can they make transistors in such a world? If yes, about how small can the transistors be?

Comment: Unless you're interested in high speed switching, simple [reed switch relays](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/electrical-electronic-relay/what-is-a-reed-relay.php) should be far more effective than hand made vacuum tubes.

Comment: Transistor is semiconductor technology, if Dr Stone can find a stone that could allow electricity to flow when certain conditions are met at room temp without considering tunneling then by all means...

Comment: You mean transistor as in logic gate? Bet that could be achieved by mechanical means and probably has. Logic gates don’t necessarily go hand in hand with electricity. Why not use water channels? Or metal cogs?

Comment: They're trying to make cell phones (somehow) in the anime...

Comment: @JohnZhau most likely it will be some sort of walkie talkie, not an actual phone.

Comment: @nzaman - The vacuum tubes in the show are needed for amplification, not switching.

Comment: @DariusArcturus A transistor is a specific type of semiconductor device. It's not a synonym for logic gate. You can make logic gate out of transistors, but you can also make logic gates out of many other things, such as vacuum tubes, [crabs](https://hackaday.com/2012/09/28/making-logic-gates-out-of-crabs/), or various mechanical means as you pointed out. But a logic gate made out of metal cogs is not a transistor.

Comment: Thanks 8bit, I did interpret transistor as a euphemism for a gate.

Answer (score 14):

No, they can't.

To make a transistor you need to be able to smelt and refine to high levels of purity specific materials like Silicon, Germanium, Boron, Phosphorus and the like, and for some of them you even need a specific crystallographic set up.

While Silicon and Phosphorus are easily found in their bound state, refining them is beyond the capabilities of stone age, even your stone age + furnaces. Let alone controlling the crystallographic orientation of Silicon.

The [Czochralski process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czochralski_process) is simply too complex for stone age,

> High-purity, semiconductor-grade silicon (only a few parts per million of impurities) is melted in a crucible at 1,425 °C (2,597 °F; 1,698 K), usually made of quartz. Dopant impurity atoms such as boron or phosphorus can be added to the molten silicon in precise amounts to dope the silicon, thus changing it into p-type or n-type silicon, with different electronic properties. A precisely oriented rod-mounted seed crystal is dipped into the molten silicon. The seed crystal's rod is slowly pulled upwards and rotated simultaneously. By precisely controlling the temperature gradients, rate of pulling and speed of rotation, it is possible to extract a large, single-crystal, cylindrical ingot from the melt. Occurrence of unwanted instabilities in the melt can be avoided by investigating and visualizing the temperature and velocity fields during the crystal growth process. This process is normally performed in an inert atmosphere, such as argon, in an inert chamber, such as quartz.

like also [zone refining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_melting)

> Zone melting (or zone refining or floating zone process or travelling melting zone) is a group of similar methods of purifying crystals, in which a narrow region of a crystal is melted, and this molten zone is moved along the crystal. The molten region melts impure solid at its forward edge and leaves a wake of purer material solidified behind it as it moves through the ingot. The impurities concentrate in the melt, and are moved to one end of the ingot.

Comment: Having made transistors for a living myself in a past life, I think you are overstating this a bit. To make high performance CMOS transistors in silicon this is probably true, and to make them very small, very low power, and very fast this is *really true!* But to make a half-dozen transistors, maybe it's actually far easier than what you describe here. I'm guessing (but don't know) that there aren't very many vacuum tubes that need to be replaced by transistors in the question.

Comment: [A workable all-transistor radio was demonstrated in August 1953 at the Düsseldorf Radio Fair by the German firm Intermetall. It was built with four of Intermetall's **hand-made transistors**, based upon the 1948 invention of the "Transistron"-germanium point-contact transistor by Herbert Mataré and Heinrich Welker.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_radio#Background)

Comment: @uhoh, I am aware of that transistor, but you still have the issue of producing Germanium. And the OP is asking for transistors which are better than vacuum tubes, smaller and easier to use. I doubt the like of the first transistor would fall in that category.

Comment: It's of course hard to tell how well the home-made vacuum tubed described in the question actually worked or what it is about them exactly that would make transistors a potentially better solution in this case. Many materials are semiconductors, and most of them are not single chemical elements, nor do they have to be single crystals. Mid-century transistor makers of course used the best technologies of the day because this was an commercially focused effort, but that doesn't mean that nothing less would do.

Comment: I would argue cleaning the wafer is harder than making it, you don't need zone refining to make a transistor, they were made for more than a decade before the process was invented.

Comment: They have glass and electricity. So they can make hydrogen and they can probably get sulfuric acid. should suffice to make germanium.

Comment: In the anime they have an entire lake of Sulfuric Acid so they don't need to look for that...